# How to pass IF statement into SSH in UNIX?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have the following bash script:

#!/bin/bash

```
set command "pgrep -x 'gedit' "

ssh -t  test@192.168.94.139 $command
```

Now, I want to include this as well in the other device:

```
if pgrep -x "gedit" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running"
else
    echo "Not Running"
fi
```

How can I make the IF Statement run on the other device? I wasn't able to include it in the ssh.

I tried this:

```
set command "pgrep -x 'gedit' "

ssh -t  test@192.168.94.139 '

if pgrep -x "gedit" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running"
else
    echo "Not Running"
fi'
```

But it didn't work! maybe because there is no command at the beginning?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of `set command "pgrep -x 'gedit' "` ?

Comment: `set` is not how you assign variables in bash; it's used to set shell options, or to set/replace the arguments to the script (i.e. `$1`, `$2`, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke `bash` with heredoc:

```sh
ssh -t test@192.168.94.139 bash <<EOF
if pgrep -x "gedit" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running"
else
    echo "Not Running"
fi
EOF
```

Comment: great! just another comment, does it work if the script is written in "expect" as well? (with #!/usr/bin/expect)

Comment: I suspect not invoking `bash` could be the reason

Comment: is it possible to pass "gedit" as a variable? for instance, getting ($pname "gedit") as parameter input from user, then use it in the bash <<EOF...> as $pname?

Comment: Yes you can use variables also like `p='gedit'` and inside heredoc use `pgrep -x "$p"`